# Sensor outputs 'around 65535' instead of 'around zero'

Tags: gyroscope

I am working with L3G4200D which a gyroscope and have interfaced it with TM4C123GXL board. I am getting the correct output for z-axis, but for both x and y-axis, I am getting something close to 65535 (when the sensor is held stable) and few outputs in between tens of outputs are correct (close to zero). And when I move the sensor the outputs of x and y-axis does go to few hundreds. Can somebody tell me what is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: are you sure that you're holding it correctly?

Comment: I have taped it to a flat box so that there is no chance of wrong outputs.

Comment: i mean, probably the "stable" position that you've mentioned, is not a default position for showing x=0 and y=0 values

Comment: I just saw outputs by holding the box upside down and the frequency of smaller values in x and y-axis outputs were increased but values around 65535 keeps showing up.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a 16-bit signed number. Therefore 65535 or 0xffff is actually -1, which is still close to 0.

Parse it as a signed 16 bit integer, instead of unsigned.